# Trying to perform mobility with an Opendaylight controller

Tags: python, sdn, opendaylight, mininet

I am using mininet to simulate a linear topology, 3 switches connected to each other and one host connected to each switch. Looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B8W54.jpg).

I used the [mobility script](https://github.com/mininet/mininet/blob/master/examples/mobility.py) provided on github to perform mobility within mininet. The script uses the default controller of Mininet.

Now I would like to use a remote Opendaylight controller to perform the mobility, or more specifically to move h1 from s1 to s2 and then back to s2.

My code is a modified version of the original mobility script. Changes are in the mobilityTest() method and the CLI was added for debugging.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

"""
Simple example of Mobility with Mininet
(aka enough rope to hang yourself.)
We move a host from s1 to s2, s2 to s3, and then back to s1.
Gotchas:
The reference controller doesn't support mobility, so we need to
manually flush the switch flow tables!
Good luck!
to-do:
- think about wifi/hub behavior
- think about clearing last hop - why doesn't that work?
"""

from mininet.node import RemoteController
from mininet.net import Mininet
from mininet.node import OVSSwitch
from mininet.topo import LinearTopo
from mininet.log import info, output, warn, setLogLevel
from mininet.examples.clustercli import CLI

from random import randint

import time


class MobilitySwitch( OVSSwitch ):
    "Switch that can reattach and rename interfaces"

    def delIntf( self, intf ):
        "Remove (and detach) an interface"
        port = self.ports[ intf ]
        del self.ports[ intf ]
        del self.intfs[ port ]
        del self.nameToIntf[ intf.name ]

    def addIntf( self, intf, rename=False, **kwargs ):
        "Add (and reparent) an interface"
        OVSSwitch.addIntf( self, intf, **kwargs )
        intf.node = self
        if rename:
            self.renameIntf( intf )

    def attach( self, intf ):
        "Attach an interface and set its port"
        port = self.ports[ intf ]
        if port:
            if self.isOldOVS():
                self.cmd( 'ovs-vsctl add-port', self, intf )
            else:
                self.cmd( 'ovs-vsctl add-port', self, intf,
                          '-- set Interface', intf,
                          'ofport_request=%s' % port )
            self.validatePort( intf )

    def validatePort( self, intf ):
        "Validate intf's OF port number"
        ofport = int( self.cmd( 'ovs-vsctl get Interface', intf,
                                'ofport' ) )
        if ofport != self.ports[ intf ]:
            warn( 'WARNING: ofport for', intf, 'is actually', ofport,
                  '\n' )

    def renameIntf( self, intf, newname='' ):
        "Rename an interface (to its canonical name)"
        intf.ifconfig( 'down' )
        if not newname:
            newname = '%s-eth%d' % ( self.name, self.ports[ intf ] )
        intf.cmd( 'ip link set', intf, 'name', newname )
        del self.nameToIntf[ intf.name ]
        intf.name = newname
        self.nameToIntf[ intf.name ] = intf
        intf.ifconfig( 'up' )

    def moveIntf( self, intf, switch, port=None, rename=True ):
        "Move one of our interfaces to another switch"
        self.detach( intf )
        self.delIntf( intf )
        switch.addIntf( intf, port=port, rename=rename )
        switch.attach( intf )


def printConnections( switches ):
    "Compactly print connected nodes to each switch"
    for sw in switches:
        output( '%s: ' % sw )
        for intf in sw.intfList():
            link = intf.link
            if link:
                intf1, intf2 = link.intf1, link.intf2
                remote = intf1 if intf1.node != sw else intf2
                output( '%s(%s) ' % ( remote.node, sw.ports[ intf ] ) )
        output( '\n' )


def moveHost( host, oldSwitch, newSwitch, newPort=None ):
    "Move a host from old switch to new switch"
    hintf, sintf = host.connectionsTo( oldSwitch )[ 0 ]
    oldSwitch.moveIntf( sintf, newSwitch, port=newPort )
    return hintf, sintf


def mobilityTest():
    "A simple test of mobility"
    info( '* Simple mobility test\n' )http://localhost:8181/restconf/operational/opendaylight-inventory:nodes/
    net = Mininet( topo=LinearTopo( 3 ), controller=lambda a: RemoteController( a, ip='127.0.0.1', port=6653), switch=MobilitySwitch )
    info( '* Starting network:\n' )
    net.start()
    printConnections( net.switches )
    info( '* Testing network\n' )
    time.sleep( 3 )
    net.pingAll()
    info( '* Identifying switch interface for h1\n' )
    h1, old = net.get( 'h1', 's1' )
    CLI( net )
    for s in 2, 3, 1:
        new = net[ 's%d' % s ]
        port = randint( 10, 20 )
        info( '* Moving', h1, 'from', old, 'to', new, 'port', port, '\n' )
        hintf, sintf = moveHost( h1, old, new, newPort=port )
        info( '*', hintf, 'is now connected to', sintf, '\n' )
        info( '* Clearing out old flows\n' )
        for sw in net.switches:
            sw.dpctl( 'del-flows' )
        info( '* Add flow rule\n' )
        CLI( net )
        info( '* New network:\n' )
        printConnections( net.switches )
        info( '* Testing connectivity:\n' )
        net.pingAll()
        old = new
    net.stop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    setLogLevel( 'info' )
mobilityTest()
```

When running the script the linear topology is set up successfully, which I can see in the delux GUI of the ODL controller. I can also ping between all hosts.

The problem occurs when mobility is performed and h1 is connected to s2.
Pinging does not work anymore.

Populating the flow-tables with a flow-rule to the controller did not solve the problem.

```
mininet> dpctl add-flow "table=0, priority=100,dl_type=0x88cc actions=CONTROLLER:65535"
*** s1 ------------------------------------------------------------------------
*** s2 ------------------------------------------------------------------------
*** s3 ------------------------------------------------------------------------
mininet> dpctl dump-flows
*** s1 ------------------------------------------------------------------------
NXST_FLOW reply (xid=0x4):
 cookie=0x0, duration=7.914s, table=0, n_packets=0, n_bytes=0, idle_age=7, priority=100,dl_type=0x88cc actions=CONTROLLER:65535
*** s2 ------------------------------------------------------------------------
NXST_FLOW reply (xid=0x4):
 cookie=0x0, duration=7.916s, table=0, n_packets=1, n_bytes=85, idle_age=2, priority=100,dl_type=0x88cc actions=CONTROLLER:65535
*** s3 ------------------------------------------------------------------------
NXST_FLOW reply (xid=0x4):
 cookie=0x0, duration=7.917s, table=0, n_packets=1, n_bytes=85, idle_age=2, priority=100,dl_type=0x88cc actions=CONTROLLER:65535
mininet> pingall
*** Ping: testing ping reachability
h1 -> X X 
h2 -> X X 
h3 -> X X 
*** Results: 100% dropped (0/6 received)
```

Then I monitored with tcpdump all interfaces when I try to ping from h1 to h2, which are now both connected to s2. h1 sends out an ARP request, which is received by the s2 switch, but this switch s2 is not forwarding the ARP request to the other switches and hosts.

I would like to know why my ping does not work anymore after performing mobility.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks